# FadeIn and FadeOut issue with Jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I've wrote html code for pop up display, when I am clicking the button I could see the pop up(FadeIn), but when  wrote jquery to fadeout.And after clicking the button to fadeIn , pop up is not getting displayed
Could anyone help me out.
Jquery:

```
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js"
  integrity="sha256-DZAnKJ/6XZ9si04Hgrsxu/8s717jcIzLy3oi35EouyE="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script>
           $(document).ready(function(){
             $("#alert-btn").click(function(){
                 $(".container").fadeIn('slow');
             });  
               $(".container").on('click',function(){
                 if(event.target).is('#btn-cancel'){
                     $(".container").fadeOut('slow');
                 }       
               }); 


           });
        </script>
```

Demo Here:

https://jsfiddle.net/VijayVj7/osv98wew/

Comment: Learn to check your browser console. There's a syntax error. First thing you should do when it doesn't work is check the console. It would have told you this immediately. `if(event.target).is('#btn-cancel')` needs to be `if(event.target.is('#btn-cancel'))`. Then try your code again. Although I'm not sure that statement will actually do what you want, but that's a secondary issue.

Answer (score 1):

you can't do that : `if(event.target).is('#btn-cancel')`

try this :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
             $("#alert-btn").click(function(){
                 $(".container").fadeIn('slow');
             });  

             $(".container #btn-cancel").on('click',function(){
                 $(".container").fadeOut('slow'); 
               });          

           });
```

https://jsfiddle.net/osv98wew/1/

Answer (score 0):

Fix your JS like:

**[jsFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/ss042uwy/)**

- missing `event` parameter
- <s>`if(event.target).is('#btn-cancel'){`</s> to `if ($(event.target).is('#btn-cancel')) {`

```
jQuery(function($) {

  $("#alert-btn").click(function() {
    $(".container").fadeIn('slow');
  });

  $(".container").on('click', function(event) {
    if ($(event.target).is('#btn-cancel')) {
      $(".container").fadeOut('slow');
    }
  });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your issue, other answers point it out. Now regarding your use case, you should delegate click event and target specific container on which event is bound:

```
$(".container").on('click', '#btn-cancel', function(event) {
  $(event.delegateTarget).fadeOut('slow');
});
```

### -jsFiddle-